# How to hide the column header for a Devexpress GridLookUpEdit?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, devexpress

I currently have a DevExpress GridControl where one of the columns have a GridLookUpEdit assigned under ColumnEdit. Yet when I run there is a column name (the display member) that shows up.

I know with a LookUpEdit you can set the column headers to invisible with `lookupedit.Properties.ShowHeader = False` but I have no clue how to make it invisible for the GridLookUpEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is run the property editor, go to columns and select the column that your lookupedit is assigned to. Then expand your column edit, then the view within, then the OptionsView. Then set ShowColumnHeaders to false. This will set all of the column headers within the lookupedit to false.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
lookupedit.Properties.View.OptionsView.ShowColumnHeaders = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to hide a column:

```
gridLookUpEdit1.Properties.View.Columns("SomeFieldName").Visible = false
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. 1. I can't access the properties of the gridLookUpEdit so I had to put gridLookUpEdit1.View.Columns("SomeFieldName").Visible = false. 2. That makes the column invisible. I only want the header of the column to be invisible so it shows the data and not the title.

Answer (score 0):

For devexpress 18.2.8

I'm using the following code to hide a column:

```
using (DataTable dt = rst.ResultSet.Tables[0].Copy())
{
    dt.Columns["Unit_ID"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
    ddlUnitOfMeasurement.Properties.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    ddlUnitOfMeasurement.Properties.ValueMember = "Unit_ID";
    ddlUnitOfMeasurement.Properties.DisplayMember = "Unit_Name"; 
}
```